# At what rate should I sample to make a dependent data stream independent?

Tags: stream, computer-vision, video-streaming

I am an undergraduate student who is volunteering in a computer vision research project. As a part of the project, I wish to make a dependent data stream (a stream in which the value of each data sample depends on the previous data sample seen), independent. For this, I need to determine a scalar at which intervals I must sample the stream so that no 2 consecutive data samples are dependent.
For instance, maybe at a jump factor of 10, that is, sampling after every 10 data points in the stream, the resultant reduced data stream is independent.
My question is how can we determine this scalar jump factor for effective sampling such that the new data stream has independent data points?
From my research, I have been unable to find any statistical test that could be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you just look at the autocorrelation of the dependent stream to determine a lag where the acf seems to drop below a certain threshold (say |0.1|)?

Comment: Yes, this works..thanks!